how does the conditional statements like if statements, or/and works in rasa "Stories". Can any one provide a practical example?
I am facing problem with if statement in rasa while writing logic for form implementation via story.
in this story I am collecting a slot "ph_number" through a form and the perform validation to check that the phone number is correct or not.
for this I am using if statement
Logic: if phone number is valid continue
else re-enter the number
the value of true/false is coming from a custom action which I am using for validation

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
